# POST with retrofit 2.0

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I'm using retrofit to communicate with my restful web service. The GET requests are working okay, the problem is when I try to make a POST request.

In my web service I have this method:

```
@POST
    @Path("/byPeriodo")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public List<ItemProdutividade> getProdutividadeByPeriodo(@FormParam("dataInicial")
    Date dataInicial, @FormParam("dataFinal") Date dataFinal,
    @FormParam("cpf") long cpf){
        return service.getProdutividadeByPeriodo(DateUtils.toLocalDate(dataInicial),
                DateUtils.toLocalDate(dataFinal), cpf);

    }
```

And in Android side I have this:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("produtividade/byPeriodo/")
Call<List<ItemProdutividade>> getProdutividadeByPeriodo(@Field("dataInicial") Date dataInicial,
                                                        @Field("dataFinal") Date dataFinal,
                                                        @Field("cpf") long cpf);
```

When I execute I get the following error:

> HTTP STATUS 400 - BAD REQUEST -The request sent by the client was
>   syntactically incorrect.

Someone knows what I have to do?

***EDIT:***

Using the retrofit log, this is the output:

```
12-16 20:06:33.521 7333-8993/br.com.empresa.oprojeto D/OkHttp: --> POST /oprojeto.webservice/rest/produtividade/byPeriodo/ HTTP/1.1
12-16 20:06:33.521 7333-8993/br.com.empresa.oprojeto D/OkHttp: dataInicial=Tue%20Dec%2016%2020%3A06%3A33%20BRST%202014&dataFinal=Wed%20Dec%2016%2020%3A06%3A33%20BRST%202015&cpf=12345678987
12-16 20:06:33.521 7333-8993/br.com.empresa.oprojeto D/OkHttp: --> END POST (125-byte body)
12-16 20:06:33.581 7333-8993/br.com.empresa.oprojeto D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request (64ms)
12-16 20:06:33.581 7333-8993/br.com.empresa.oprojeto D/OkHttp: Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
12-16 20:06:33.581 7333-8993/br.com.empresa.oprojeto D/OkHttp: Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
12-16 20:06:33.581 7333-8993/br.com.empresa.oprojeto D/OkHttp: Content-Language: en
12-16 20:06:33.581 7333-8993/br.com.empresa.oprojeto D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 1033
12-16 20:06:33.581 7333-8993/br.com.empresa.oprojeto D/OkHttp: Date: Wed, 16 Dec 2015 22:06:31 GMT
12-16 20:06:33.581 7333-8993/br.com.empresa.oprojeto D/OkHttp: Connection: close
12-16 20:06:33.581 7333-8993/br.com.empresa.oprojeto D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1
12-16 20:06:33.581 7333-8993/br.com.empresa.oprojeto D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1450303593575
12-16 20:06:33.581 7333-8993/br.com.empresa.oprojeto D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1450303593591
12-16 20:06:33.581 7333-8993/br.com.empresa.oprojeto D/OkHttp: <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/8.0.29 - Error report</title><style type="text/css">H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}.line {height: 1px; background-color: #525D76; border: none;}</style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 400 - Bad Request</h1><div class="line"></div><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>Bad Request</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.</u></p><hr class="line"><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.0.29</h3></body></html>
12-16 20:06:33.581 7333-8993/br.com.empresa.oprojeto D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (1033-byte body)
```

Comment: could you recheck the path and post path

Comment: I already done that. I use a base url (`http://IP_ADDRESS:8080/project/rest/`) and for get requests it works fine. In the post path I already tried `produtividade/byPeriodo` and `produtividade/byPeriodo/`. In both I get the same error.

Comment: any errors in you android log ?

Comment: No errors in log. I get the error message that I put in the question using the response of Retrofit: `response.errorBody().string()`

Comment: I update the question and add the retrofit log.

Comment: just to make sure, you are able to post on that form using a local browser or similar.

Comment: Yes, I tested using Postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem. I was sending type java.util.Date as a parameter and I decided to change to type Long (or long). So, my web service method is now:

```
@POST
    @Path("/byPeriodo")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public List<ItemProdutividade> getProdutividadeByPeriodo(@FormParam("dataInicial")
    long dataInicial, @FormParam("dataFinal") long dataFinal,
    @FormParam("cpf") long cpf){
        return service.getProdutividadeByPeriodo(DateUtils.toLocalDate(new Date(dataInicial)),
                DateUtils.toLocalDate(new Date(dataFinal)), cpf);
    }
```

The secret was to change type Date to long and do that: `new Date(long)`.